# Android, create a sectioned expandable recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, expandablerecyclerview

Is there a way to create an expandable `RecyclerView` with sections?
I can create an expandable `RecyclerView` using this [expandable recycler view](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view)
and of course I can create a sectioned  `RecyclerView` separately ... But, I don't know how to have both in the same `RecyclerView`.

Comment: https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview

Comment: https://bignerdranch.github.io/expandable-recycler-view/